# How to convert CVImageBufferRef of kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8 to kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA using Metal framework

Tags: cocoa, metal, image-scaling, metalkit

I am working on scaling image buffers returned from AVCaptureSession using Metal kit. The default pixel format of AVCaptureSession out is kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8.

How do I convert these buffers to kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA using Metal framework?

PS: I don't want solution involving operations that increase the memory or the CPU size.

Side question: If anyone could help me on how to scale image buffer of format '2vuy' using Metal kit, I could skip pixel format conversion and get the desired result.

Comment: I think you can do this with Accelerate, but, I'm almost certain you are going to need to allocate an additional buffer for the results.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue (almost)

Comment: Im still figuring out. Will let you know if i get it. Please help me out if you find any.

Comment: I was able to change the format in the decompressor - VTDecompressionSessionCreate - setting the destinationImageBufferAttributes to [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
     nil];